# How to integrate a bootstrap navbar in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've been working on a revision of a website.
We use Wordpress and the responsive navigation bar is not good.
When I use a mobile device, I want to have something like:

[image]

The nav bar of the website is only realized by Wordpress, and I want to use Bootstrap.
The navbar's code is :

```
   <?php responsive_container(); // before container hook ?>
<div id="container" class="hfeed clear <?php if($GLOBALS['home'] == 1) { ?> home <?php } ?>" >

    <?php responsive_header(); // before header hook ?>
    <!-- <a href="javascript:gaOptout()">Cliquez ici pour vous opposer aux cookies de mesure d'audience de Google</a> -->
    <div id="header" class="clearfix">
        <div class="wrap">

            <?php responsive_in_header(); // header hook ?>


            <?php if ($is_blog!=1){ ?>

                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" width="266" alt="logo xee"/></a>
                </div>

                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                    ));
                    ?>

            <?php } else { ?>
```

I've tried to implement a responsive button with Bootstrap like that:

```
<?php responsive_in_header(); // header hook ?>

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" style="float: left">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<?php if ($is_blog!=1){ ?>

    <div id="logo">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" width="266" alt="logo xee"/></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        ));
        ?>
        </ul>>
    </div>
```

but the result is on: [wwwtest.xee.com](http://wwwtest.xee.com) using the device emulator by chrome

Have you ever seen this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First off, your markup looks incomplete. The is no `nav`, no `container`and no `navbar-header`. I'd suggest that you take the menu example code and start from that. Like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       [..]
```

Also when working with Wordpress I'd like to use a menu walker. A walker walks through your menu structure and creates the proper menu. There is a very good bootstrap menu walker:

https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

The documentation is pretty good and you should be able to get your menu working. It's really almost only copy and paste with little adjustments.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
            <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
        </a>
</div>

    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
</div>
</nav>
```

The rest is just CSS formatting. Tell me if you get better results.

Comment: Now my navbar is over the container div, do you know how can i fix it ?

Comment: Your additional navbar has `position: absolute`set. If you want your navbar to be fixed on top of your page you should use Bootstrap's `navbar-fixed-top` class and set a padding-top to the body. You can see an example here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ And if you're using Bootstrap try to use their structure and classes. Don't mix it too much with your own stuff. You can customize Bootstrap easily using LESS (e.g.: http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled in the past integrating bootstrap with wordpress, since many themes use the same class names as bootstrap. In particular, you might want to make sure that none of the wordpress theme's javascript or css is looking for elements with `.nav`, `.navbar`, or `.container`.